# Gitlab on a Compute Engine instance is not available

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gitlab, google-compute-engine

We deployed the Gitlab server on a Compute Engine instance with an attached static external IP address. From time to time, the server is unavailable to us upon requests from Russia. When using the "tracert" command, packets do not go beyond the address 209.85.243.152 (Google LLC). However, the Gitlab site is fully accessible upon requests from other regions at any time.

Comment: Are you trying to use any third party services or IPS software e.g SSHGuard which might not configured correctly on your host causing this issue ?

How are you trying to connect to the server ?

Also double check the ports open for your instance by running nmap instance-name -Pn -p port-number

Comment: @NamanParekh, thanks for the answer. I used a Ubuntu 18.04.4 image. In addition to the GitLab package, only the Nano editor was installed. Access to the GitLab web interface is configured through port 443 (opened). Most of the time the site is accessible without problems, but sometimes there is no access from my region. However, when I try to access through a proxy server located in another country, the site is fully accessible. After a couple of hours, the problem goes away.

Comment: From which particular region you trying to access your gitlab server when facing error and also the region from where you were successfully access it ? In addition, How are you trying to access it ?

Comment: The region is St. Petersburg, Russia. The server is always accessible from Frankfurt, London, Helsinki and Oregon. I am trying to access the service’s website through the Google Chrome and Safary browsers, and also send a GET request through Postman.

Comment: Try disabled "Send Postman Token Header" also are you able to ping it from different region or ssh ?

Comment: I got "Network error: Connection timed out" when trying ssh via PuTTY (22 port opened).

Comment: The server is completely unavailable from my region, regardless of how it interacts (protocols, ports, utilities).
After some time, it becomes active again and I can go to the Gitlab interface, connect via SSH or send requests to Postman without any problems.
The way I try to access it from my device is clearly not the cause of the problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was preinstalled sshguard, which mistakenly added my IP to the list of blocked ones.
There is a [solution instruction](https://serverfault.com/a/895176/574958) in this answer.

Comment: Great !! so provided recommendation of checking IPS software helped. Thanks for updating.